# How to obtain SCARD_ATTR_DEVICE_UNIT correctly

Tags: driver, smartcard, smartcard-reader, pcsc, umdf

I am developing a smartcard UMDF windows driver. I would like to achieve following behaviour:

When listing all connected readers by using API call [SCardListReaders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379793(v=vs.85).aspx) I want to retrieve the correct friendly names for each attached reader. So for example if I have two readers of same brand I want this to be returned by the driver:

```
SmartcardBrand USBReader 0
SmartcardBrand USBReader 1
```

I know that the friendly name is composed of the attributes `SCARD_ATTR_VENDOR_NAME`, `SCARD_ATTR_VENDOR_IFD_TYPE` and `SCARD_ATTR_DEVICE_UNIT` the driver returns.

My question is, in my driver, how can I distinguish between `SmartcardBrand USBReader 0` and `SmartcardBrand USBReader 1`?

What shall I return to the OS when `SCARD_ATTR_DEVICE_UNIT` is requested. I cannot use and increment a global static variable in my driver because every time a new reader gets connected a new UMDF host process is launched (I can see it in the task manager) resulting in a separate new memory area.

What is the proper way of counting device instances in a UMDF driver?

---

I solved the problem by using [memory-mapped files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379793(v=vs.85).aspx). Basically each UMDF process of my driver creates a memory-mapped file with name of the reader's friendly name. When an other process tries to create a file with the same name it indicates that a driver is already running.

However, there is inconsistency when I connect a reader which uses my driver and afterwards connect a reader which uses Windows native driver. The Windows driver will not see my memory-mapped file I created and apply index 0 for its device.

I found out that, when the Windows driver is loaded it queries `SCARD_ATTR_VENDOR_IFD_TYPE`, `SCARD_ATTR_VENDOR_IFD_TYPE` and `SCARD_ATTR_DEVICE_UNIT` from my driver (and from all other drivers currently loaded). I guess this way the Windows driver can know which device units are taken and apply a free one to its reader.